# Implementing interfaces on vueJS

Tags: interface, vuejs2

I'm currently working on an vue application. For some development reasons I need to implement interfaces. The problem is that is not possible to create it on `.js` file, I absolutly need a `.ts` file. So when I create a `.ts` file and export this interface, and then I import into my `.vue` file my project throw me the following error:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

After some research, I need to add a "loader" to webpack configuration but I have absolutely no idea to do it... Someone could help me please?

Sorry if my question have some mistakes, English is not my native language.

Comment: Basically, you need TypeScript support with Vue. [Jump to the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use typescript in vue.

[This page](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) tells you how to modify the webpack config. This should fix the "loader" error you're getting.

[This page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) covers using typescript for vue components.

Between the two, you should be fine.